# find a specific id within a html dl

Tags: jquery

I want to match the value (html) of a dd tag against another variable. For example, if the id of a dd tag is equal to id1 then i need to match the value of against the stored variable.

I have this so far, which doesn't fall into the alert

```
 var matchedItem = msg.d[1][0]["MatchedItem"];
 var matchedTag = msg.d[1][0]["MatchedTag"];

 $('dd').find( $("#" + matchedTag) ).each( function () {
    if ( matchedItem == $(this).html() ) {
       alert("we have a match");
    }
 });
```

*** EDIT ****
matchedItem = 'Brian'
matchedTag = 'Customer Name'

So, for each customer name. if Brian is matched then alert.

any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: `id` will be always unique, so `if( $("#" + matchedTag).html() == matchedItem ){}` will be enough

Comment: `$('dd').find($("#" + matchedTag)).each(function () {` looks like you have multiple element with same id ...id shouyld be unique.. and using id selector there is no need of using each.

Comment: could you give us hypethetical values for matchedTag and matchedItem please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming  matchedTag is  the id of the element you want the html of..then only this should work

```
   if ($("#" + matchedTag).html()==matchedItem){
           alert("we have a match");
   }
```

Comment: ok, think i may need a rethink as this isn't working. I may need to loop through all the dd's with a class name, and then check these values against matchedItem?

Comment: yes... if you have multiple elements then class is the way to go... without HTML, it is hard to say..:)

Answer (score 0):

you've got a syntax error here:

```
$('dd').find("#" + matchedTag).each(function () {
       if (matchedItem == $(this).html()) {
          alert("we have a match");
       }
});
```

Tell me if it works now

also; if you have multiple elements with exactly the same id in one html page, the jquery will either fail, or only work on one element

Comment: nope didn't work. I need to change this to be a class check instead of ID - stupidly forgot about the unique

Comment: yeah, if you have duplicate ids, then - same as i added in the end of my answer